# Create undo/redo command based on propertyvaluechange event

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I want to create `undo/redo command` which can set new/old value to some properties. I use `propertygrid` to manipulate properties value. I try to do it using `PropertyValueChanged event`.

My try:

```
private void pg_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = propertyGrid.SelectedObject;
    var propertyName = e.ChangedItem.PropertyDescriptor.Name;
    PropertyInfo pi = item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

    var oldValue = e.OldValue;
    var newValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);

    //create command here
}
```

This works fine if property's parent is `propertyGrid.SelectedObject`.
But if I have class:

```
Class A {
    public Size Size {get;set;}
}
```

it doesn't work sometimes. 
Example: `propertyGrid.SelectedObject` is `Class A`, `propertyName` is `Width`, `Width` isn't `Class A` property, it is `Size` property, so I got exception.

How can I resolve this problem? How to create `undo/redo command` to this situation?

Comment: Why on earth would you write `asm.GetType(item.GetType().FullName)`?

Comment: I don't understand. When I editing `Width`, `asm.GetType(item.GetType().FullName)` return `Class A` instead `Size`. It is obvious, because `item` is `propertygrid.selectedobject`. But my question is how can I get `Size`

Comment: When I wrote this, I don't think about this situation.. This is my first time, when I try to use property grid..

Comment: I look again and I change `asm.GetType(item.GetType().FullName)` to `item.GetType()`. But it doesn't solve problem.. because problem is not to get `item's` type, but `property` parent..

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?

```
private void pg_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var item = e.ChangedItem;
  var propertyName = item.PropertyDescriptor.Name;
  PropertyInfo pi = item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

  var oldValue = e.OldValue;
  var newValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);

  //create command here
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. My code is the same like yours (I edited my code 15 minutes before your answer)

Comment: The first line of the method body in my suggestion is different from the first line of your question?

Comment: oh, you are right. I did not notice this. But it also doesn't work

Comment: You're going to have to actually implement the command in order for this to work. The OP is / was a newbie.

Comment: You can use `e.ChangedItem.Value` instead of `PropertyInfo.GetValue`

Answer (score 0):

Find the class name of the data in the property grid:

```
e.ChangedItem.PropertyDescriptor.ComponentType.Name
```

Then record the undo information including the class name. So when the user undoes the change you know which class needs to be undone.

```
private void pg_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
        string className = e.ChangedItem.PropertyDescriptor.ComponentType.Name;
        string propertyName = e.ChangedItem.PropertyDescriptor.Name;

        var oldValue = e.OldValue;
        var newValue = e.ChangedItem.Value;

        //Record the above variables in your undo class
        //Something like
        RedoClass.AddToUndoList(className,propertyName,oldValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally this worked for me:

```cs
private void prg_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.ChangedItem;
    var propertyName = item.PropertyDescriptor.Name;
    PropertyInfo pi = prg.SelectedObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

    var oldValue = e.OldValue;
    pi.SetValue(prg.SelectedObject, oldValue, null);
}
```

Where prg is the name of the PropertyGrid